# Windows Forms - Open ShowDialog without freezing parent of owner

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I have three forms (Form1, Form2, Form3), and my need would be:

Form1 opens Form2 with `.Show()`, without freezing Form1.

Form2 opens Form3 with `.ShowDialog()` without freezing Form1.

I tried passing the owner inside the `.Show(this)` and `.ShowDialog(this)`

Comment: The Modal state set by ShowDialog is meant to block the application not a (certain) form.  If you want something like that you need to use Show and disable the parent then yourself and maintain that state somehow if needed to correctly enable that form again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/17034

Answer (score 2):

There are many differences when using `Form.Show()` and `Form.ShowDialog()`.

| `Form.Show()` | `Form.ShowDialog()` |
| --- | --- |
| `Form.Show()`: When using `Form.Show()`, the form appears as a non-blocking window, allowing users to interact with other forms simultaneously. | `Form.ShowDialog()`: With `Form.ShowDialog()`, the form displays as a modal dialog, preventing interaction with other forms until it's closed. |
| **Code Execution**: `Form.Show()`: The calling code continues execution immediately after showing the form. | **Code Execution**: `Form.ShowDialog()`: Code execution in the calling method pauses until the modal dialog is closed. |
| **Return Value**: `Form.Show()`: Doesn't return a specific value related to the form. | **Return Value**: `Form.ShowDialog()`: Returns a value indicating the user's action in the dialog. |
| **Parent-Child Relationship**: `Form.Show()`: The form is not automatically a child of the calling form. | **Parent-Child Relationship**: `Form.ShowDialog()`: The form is always a child of the calling form. |
| **Usage Scenario**: `Form.Show()`: Ideal for non-blocking interactions and simultaneous use of multiple forms. | **Usage Scenario**: `Form.ShowDialog()`: Used for critical actions requiring user input or confirmation. |

I'm not entirely certain I fully understand your question, but based on my understanding, it seems like you can't use `Form.ShowDialog()` or `Form.ShowDialog(owner)` without freezing other forms. You've to use `Form.Show()` or `Form.Show(owner)` instead. If I'm mistaken or if you could provide more clarification, I'd be glad to revise my answer accordingly.